# I want to dislay button same line with span when text overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

When use text overflow and button same line, the button have problem

Here are my code

```css
a {
  float: right;
}

li {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<h1>The ul element</h1>

<ul>
  <li><span>Create a list inside a list (a nested list)</span><a href="">x</a></li>
  <li><span>Create</span><a href="">x</a></li>
  <li><span>Create a list inside a list (a nested list)</span><a href="">x</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Post some code plz. otherwise we can't help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - Please take the [tour] and read our [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question. For starters, you can include a [mre] of the issue you want to troubleshoot

Comment: with the code provided, the x is aligned correctly.. I believe you need to set the width of the li correctly and it will work

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using flex for this.

```
<h1>The ul element</h1>

<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Create a list inside a list (a nested list)</span>
    <a href="">x</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Create</span>
    <a href="">x</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Create a list inside a list (a nested list)</span>
    <a href="">x</a>
  </li>
</ul>

a{
display: inline-block;
width: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
}

li{
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Here is a demo of how it would work
https://jsfiddle.net/Oggy49/tj2h40wp/#&togetherjs=6dSiIoy042

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```css
a {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

li {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<h1>The ul element</h1>

<ul>
  <li><span>Create a list inside a list (a nested list)</span><a href="">x</a></li>
  <li><span>Create</span><a href="">x</a></li>
  <li><span>Create a list inside a list (a nested list)</span><a href="">x</a></li>
</ul>
```